# Regex to match end of the string and capture the part before end of the string perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I'm trying to match any string with the regex that ends with /? and extract the string before /?

Below is my code:

```
$input = "boringinterestingboring/?";
if($input =~ /(.*)\/?$/) {
    print "$1\n";
}
else {
    print "not matched";
}
```

I'm trying to capture `"boringinterestingboring"` using `(.*)` but it's not doing that, instead it captures the whole string.

How should i get only the string before /?.

Please help.

Comment: You need to escape the `?` because it's a special character (quantifier that matches the preceding group 1 or 0 times).

Comment: please make it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

To match everything up to, but not including, a `/?`:

```
.*(?=/\?)
```

If you’re not sure about escaping, you can use a character class to do the escaping for you:

```
.*(?=/[?])
```

Answer (score 1):

It may seem duplicate, but as the answer of your question,
Your regex need to be:

```
/(.*)\/\?$/
```

or

```
/(.*)(?=\/\?$)/
```

Example:

```
$input = "boringinterestingboring/?";
print "Use \$1: $1\n" if($input =~ /(.*)\/\?$/);
print "Use \$1: $1\n" if($input =~ /(.*)(?=\/\?$)/);
print "Use \$&: $&\n" if($input =~ /.*(?=\/\?$)/);
```

Output:

```
Use $1: boringinterestingboring
Use $1: boringinterestingboring
Use $&: boringinterestingboring
```

Different ways, same destination. But either way, you should escape `?` too, or put it in `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using positive lookahead. The assertion `(?=..)` will match `/?` but will not make it part of the capturing group even if it is nested in another group.

```
$ echo "boringinterestingboring/?" | perl -ne ' ($x)=/(boringinterestingboring(?=\/\?))/ ; print $x '
boringinterestingboring
$
```

Negative test case. Below prints nothing

```
$ echo "boringinterestingboring#?" | perl -ne ' ($x)=/(boringinterestingboring(?=\/\?))/ ; print $x '

$
```